# calling controller method in href in a button, in a view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

iam back with another question to do with mvc and codeigniter. just getting a bit confused with the concept of MVC.  First of all i have a button. i want it to reference another page. how i was going to access the next "view" or page was from this view was with a simple href="" inside a button like below.

```
href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/admin"
```

but this is a call to a method in my controller, which redirects to admin page. from what ive read this is bad practice as you cant call a controller method from a view. fair enough. but how do i actually link to the next page then? cheers

Comment: you are NOT calling a controller method from the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always interact with the controller directly from the view. Calling `href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/admin"` means you interacting with the `admin function` of `user controller` and this is perfectly fine. No worries.

Comment: thank you again sir! alright, hopefully this MVC stuff will stay in my head at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/admin')?>">
```

And here is the controller method of user class to which you are going

```
function admin(){
    $this->load->view('mypage');
}
```

Make sure you allow it to access. I mean there is no  check in constructor to redirect somewhere else.